# How can a genetic algorithm optimize a network of vertices which have variables to tune themselves?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

How can I apply crossover to also include the vertex variables, not only the connections? Since two parent networks may be totally different, a vertex will not always have a counterpart to crossover with. How do I overcome this problem? Solely relying on mutation to optimize the VV is not effective.
Request

Comment: The question is a bit unspecific; please include a small example.

Comment: For example, cartesian genetic programming rely only on selection and mutation. If you have a network structure with multiple nodes and you tried combine some of them, result will be with high probability junk.

Comment: @Codor I want to optimize a chemical process network. This task includes the **selection** of the best unit operations (distillation, extraction, etc.), **connection** of the different nodes in the best possible way and **optimizing internal variables** of the unit operations (e.g. size of the distillation column).

Comment: @viceriel You might be right. What would you suggest instead of a "normal" genetic algorithm?

Comment: I would try high mutation, natural selection, infusion of random material and long time for evolution. I once heard about strange algorithm, "angel and mortals". Solutions are mortals and they lives and moves on 2D grid. Solutions live time is based on their fitness. On the 2D grid also lives the angels, when solution is near angel, angel modifies him(mutation equivalent) and for solution is computed fitness again. But this approach is questionable. I know about this topic only one set-up advice, count of angles should be more than solution count.

Comment: @viceriel But that doesn't solve the problem of vertex variable optimization relying on random search / mutation

Comment: Ok, philosophic question. if there exists great way how to perform crossover, will this additional help enough to solve your problem?

Comment: @viceriel Maybe, maybe not. See, the thing is, the vertex variable optimization solely relying on mutation disqualifies the algorithm. Imagine a GA without crossover. That is basically a combination of random search and hill climbing. A pretty useless thing. If there is a way of effectively performing crossover, that would certainly help.